# Excluding certain words found in list of files with list of exclusion terms

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Trying to exclude certain terms from a list as shown below.  I'm sure I'm missing something.

```
dir = r'C:\Temo'
exclude = ['test', 'Test', 'debug', 'Debug']

for item in exclude:
    new_list = [os.path.join(dir, files)
                for files in os.listdir(dir)
                if files.endswith(".csv") and item not in files]
```

This results in excluding only 1 term from the exclude list, although the others are present. I'm sure I'm missing something simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `all()` in list comprehension to filter out items. Also, you can use `str.lower` to not include all variations of file-names (lower/upper-case):

```
import os

dir = r'C:\Temo'
exclude = ['test', 'debug']

new_list = [os.path.join(dir, file)
            for file in os.listdir(dir)
            if file.endswith(".csv") and all(ex not in file.lower() for ex in exclude)]

print(new_list)
```